# Loading images from json url to listview, images are not fixed

Tags: android, json, android-image

I am new to android app, i am trying to add images and text in listview and the response from server is JSON response. Now i added text in listview correspondingly i need to add images to each text, where images are not fixed.i am using the following code but nothing is displaying in my emulator.
can any one correct me where am i going wrong?

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
JSONArray posts = null;

// All static variables
static final String URL = "http://website/?json=get_recent_posts";



static final String KEY_POSTS = "posts";
static final String KEY_ID = "id";
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
static final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumbnail";
static final String KEY_IMAGES = "images";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


    // Creating JSON Parser instance
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);
            try {
            posts = json.getJSONArray(KEY_POSTS);
    // looping through all song nodes <song>
            for(int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(KEY_ID);
                String title = c.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                String date = c.getString(KEY_DATE);
                String content = c.getString(KEY_CONTENT);

                // Phone number is agin  JSON Object
                JSONObject author = c.getJSONObject(KEY_AUTHOR);
                String name = author.getString(KEY_NAME);

                JSONObject images = c.getJSONObject(KEY_IMAGES);
                String thumbnail = images.getString(KEY_THUMB_URL);

        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        map.put(KEY_ID, id);
        map.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        map.put(KEY_DATE, date);
        map.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        map.put(KEY_CONTENT, content);
        map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,thumbnail);
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        songsList.add(map);
            }   
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

                }


    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Getting adapter by passing json data ArrayList
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    // Click event for single list row
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


        }
    });     
}   
 }
```

LazyAdapter.java

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView date = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist); // artist name
    TextView content = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.duration);  // duration
    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); 
    // duration
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
    song = data.get(position);


    ListView list;
    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_TITLE));
    date.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_DATE));
    content.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_CONTENT));
    name.setText(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_NAME));

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(CustomizedListView.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

imageloader.java

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;
private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
ExecutorService executorService; 

public ImageLoader(Context context){
    fileCache=new FileCache(context);
    executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id = R.drawable.no_image;
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null)
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
private class PhotoToLoad
{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u; 
        imageView=i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
    String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
        return true;
    return false;
}

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null)
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

public void clearCache() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

Comment: Are you getting the json response properly in the emulator?

Comment: Any errors/ exceptions in Logcat?

Comment: Have you added WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest?

Comment: yes included  WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest @user603125

Comment: logcat is not showing any error

Answer (score 0):

Use Lazylist Adapter

***For Example:***

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> ar=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

LazyAdapter adapter=new LazyAdapter(con, ar);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    //public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
    private URL url;
    private Bitmap bmp;

    public LazyAdapter(Context a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lis, null);   
        TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView11); // title
        TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView21); // artist nameduration
        ImageView im=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
        song = data.get(position);

        // Setting all values in listview
        title.setText(song.get("name"));
        artist.setText(song.get("adr"));
        try {
            url = new URL(song.get("icon"));
             bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
               im.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return vi;
    }
}
```